# Set id into createElement() using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner for  js. I want set id into these created tags.but it didn't work.

```
var d1=document.createElement("div");
d1.setAttribute("class","container");         
var b3= document.createElement("button");
b3.setAttribute("class","btn btn-default");
b3.innerHTML="View More";
b3.setIdAttribute("id","b3");
d1.appendChild(b3);
```

Comment: `d1.setAttribute("id","b3");`/ `d1.id="b3"`

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a different function for setting the `id` attribute than `class`?

Comment: Are you sure you really need an `id` on a dynamically-created element?

Comment: I want to set id into b3 button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set the DOM property `id`:

```
b3.id = "b3";
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for every one who responded me.

```
var d1=document.createElement("div");
d1.setAttribute("class","container");         
var b3= document.createElement("button");
b3.setAttribute("class","btn btn-default");
b3.innerHTML="View More";
b3.setAttribute("id","b3");//b3 means the name of the id
d1.appendChild(b3);
```